# HTML CSS Button text totally not centered

Tags: html, css

I created the following button:

```css
.project-grid {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px 75%;
    column-gap: 50px;
}

.left-side {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

.searchbar-box {
    padding-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    height: 40px;
    align-items: center;
}

.searchbar-box input[type=text] {
    width: 70%;
}

.searchbar-box input[type=text], select {
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.searchbar-box input[type=image] {
    padding-left: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.searchbar-box input[type=image]:hover {
    transform: scale(1.25);
    transition: 0.3s ease transform, 0.3s ease opacity;
}

#btnAddProject {
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    /*border: none;*/
    background-color: transparent;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: 0.3s ease transform, 0.3s ease opacity;
}

#btnAddProject:hover {
    color: rgb(28, 143, 238);
    transform: scale(1.25);
    transition: 0.3s ease transform, 0.3s ease opacity; 
}
```

```html
<div class="project-grid">
    <div class="left-side">
        <div class="searchbar-box" style="padding-bottom: 65px;">
            <input type="text" id="searchBar" name="txtSearch" class="searchbar" placeholder="Search...">
            <button id="btnAddProject" onClick="projectListController.addNewProject()">+</button>
        </div>
```

But as you can see the `+` in the button isn't centered vertical perfectly. I already tried setting: `vertical-align: center;` and `align-items: center;` but that doesn't change anything. How can I center the button text, no matter the screen size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `display: flex` to `#btnAddProject`.

```css
.project-grid {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px 75%;
    column-gap: 50px;
}

.left-side {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

.searchbar-box {
    padding-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    height: 40px;
    align-items: center;
}

.searchbar-box input[type=text] {
    width: 70%;
}

.searchbar-box input[type=text], select {
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.searchbar-box input[type=image] {
    padding-left: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.searchbar-box input[type=image]:hover {
    transform: scale(1.25);
    transition: 0.3s ease transform, 0.3s ease opacity;
}

#btnAddProject {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    /*border: none;*/
    background-color: transparent;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: 0.3s ease transform, 0.3s ease opacity;
}

#btnAddProject:hover {
    color: rgb(28, 143, 238);
    transform: scale(1.25);
    transition: 0.3s ease transform, 0.3s ease opacity; 
}
```

```html
<div class="project-grid">
    <div class="left-side">
        <div class="searchbar-box" style="padding-bottom: 65px;">
            <input type="text" id="searchBar" name="txtSearch" class="searchbar" placeholder="Search...">
            <button id="btnAddProject" onClick="projectListController.addNewProject()">+</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: This is later after my answer, nice copy / paste. @A.Vreeswijk you should give to the oldest one in this case, but whatever

Comment: @MaxiGui, I write it before your answer appears here. It's not a copy/paste, it's just the same obvious solution.

Comment: And after when you see, this is the same answer, as I posted, don't you think it is worth to not get duplicate answer on same problem ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: flex;` and `justify-content: center;` along with `align-items: center;`. I also enclosed '+' with `span` so it makes easier to style the text. ( I also used -ve `margin-top`, play with it if you want to).

```css
.project-grid {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px 75%;
    column-gap: 50px;
}

.left-side {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

.searchbar-box {
    padding-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    height: 40px;
    align-items: center;
}

.searchbar-box input[type=text] {
    width: 70%;
}

.searchbar-box input[type=text], select {
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.searchbar-box input[type=image] {
    padding-left: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.searchbar-box input[type=image]:hover {
    transform: scale(1.25);
    transition: 0.3s ease transform, 0.3s ease opacity;
}

#btnAddProject {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
    font-size: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    /*border: none;*/
    background-color: transparent;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: 0.3s ease transform, 0.3s ease opacity;
}

#btnAddProject span{
  margin-top: -6px;
}

#btnAddProject:hover {
    color: rgb(28, 143, 238);
    transform: scale(1.25);
    transition: 0.3s ease transform, 0.3s ease opacity; 
}
```

```html
<div class="project-grid">
    <div class="left-side">
        <div class="searchbar-box" style="padding-bottom: 65px;">
            <input type="text" id="searchBar" name="txtSearch" class="searchbar" placeholder="Search...">
            <button id="btnAddProject" onClick="projectListController.addNewProject()">
            <span>+</span></button>
        </div>
```

Comment: This is the only answer where the example code actually puts the `+` in the vertical **and** horizontal centre (even then I'm not convinced it's perfectly veritically centred).

Comment: @Martin It's because of negative `margin-top`. You can remove it if you don't like it.

Comment: No, this makes this answer better, in my view.

Answer (score 0):

Set `display:flex` on your button:

DEMO:

```css
.project-grid {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 200px 75%;
    column-gap: 50px;
}

.left-side {
    display: block;
    padding-left: 40px;
}

.searchbar-box {
    padding-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    height: 40px;
    align-items: center;
}

.searchbar-box input[type=text] {
    width: 70%;
}

.searchbar-box input[type=text], select {
    padding: 12px 20px;
    margin: 8px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.searchbar-box input[type=image] {
    padding-left: 10px;
    height: 30px;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.searchbar-box input[type=image]:hover {
    transform: scale(1.25);
    transition: 0.3s ease transform, 0.3s ease opacity;
}

#btnAddProject {
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    /*border: none;*/
    background-color: transparent;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: 0.3s ease transform, 0.3s ease opacity;
    
    /**ADDED**/
    display: flex;
}

#btnAddProject:hover {
    color: rgb(28, 143, 238);
    transform: scale(1.25);
    transition: 0.3s ease transform, 0.3s ease opacity; 
}
```

```html
<div class="project-grid">
    <div class="left-side">
        <div class="searchbar-box" style="padding-bottom: 65px;">
            <input type="text" id="searchBar" name="txtSearch" class="searchbar" placeholder="Search...">
            <button id="btnAddProject" onClick="projectListController.addNewProject()">+</button>
        </div>
```